# what Regex Expression do we need to use in this scenario

Tags: regex

what Regex Expression do we need to use in this scenario

Iam looking to have Regular Expression where we need to validate the user  that he cannot enter a value of "ZERO"
is this correct "regex":/^0$/,
Valid responses are: 
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,
Invalid Responses are 
0

Comment: Langauge? Example? Are we trying to MATCH a 0 or match anything but 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and it is rather complicated and clumsy to write a regex saying "but not x". Try to avoid regexes in that case.

Comment: And the regex you are looking for is: /^[^0].*$/

Comment: @AndeKR:I should avoid the User entering  value "0" for the input .And i tried the same thing and it is not working

Comment: I am pretty sure the regex is working. How is your regex used, in a program? Maybe you called your regex matching function in the wrong way? What do you mean "it is not working"?

Comment: @AndreKR, a problem with yours is that it would ban `0mar` as a name. Although it looks like the solution space should be all numbers now.

Answer (score 1):

Often times, it's helpful to list a set of valid and invalid responses.

Valid:

- `joe`
- `bob`
- `zero`
- `amy0`
- `s0nny`
- `0mar`

Invalid:

- `0`

If this is the case, then the easiest solution is to say `username == "0"`, and skip the regular expression. If, rather, you need to make sure that the `0` can not be at the front of any string, then something like `username[0] == '0'` would work.

On the other hand, if you want to make sure that there are no `0` characters anywhere in the string, then I would use something like `not username.contains('0')`.

I guess what I'm getting at is that this doesn't sound like a problem that demands a regular expression.

Comment: I should avoid the User Entering "0" value for that I need a regularexpression

Comment: @Someone: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean by that. Unless AndreKR's solution is what you want, please edit your question and add a table of valid and invalid responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this...

> ^(0.+|[^0].*)$

You can test it here...

http://regexpal.com